# Hide map objects temporarily in Here Navigate edition

Tags: heremaps, heremaps-android-sdk

Previously in the Here maps Premium edition you could toggle the visibility of a map object via `mapObject.isVisible`. There seems to be no such property in the new Navigate edition, so are we supposed to completely remove/add them each time we want to hide a map object?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct. There is no such convenience method. Instead, you simply remove the map item. Or add it again later. This is a fast operation that happens on the next frame, so there is actually no need to control the visibility on the item itself.

However, what you can do is to call `setVisibilityRanges()`. This will show/hide e.g. a map marker dependent on zoom level. And this can be also updated on-the-fly.